# Filter With() in Query Scope

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
Controller    
$r = \App\User::whereIn('id',  $user_ids)->withPosts($category_id)->get();

User model
public function scopeWithPosts($query, $category_id)
    {
        return $query->with('posts')->where('category_id', $category_id);
    }
```

I have been at this for too many hours now.

I am trying to use with() along with an query scope to add an extra filter to the relationship.

However it gives me the error " category_id not existing in users table"? What am I missing? 
Laravel 6

Comment: To make a relation, you must create a relationship method in user model and map appropriate primary key and foreign key. Can't say more, need more information and some more code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is that you are expecting the `with('posts')` function to return a query that is relative to the Posts ORM model. It won't, it will still return a reference to the original query. What you will find is that the `with` function returns `$this`, so you'll always get the original query.

What you are attempting is a SQL query to find the `User`, followed by another SQL query to get all the `Post` records of that user, with those posts filtered by category. So

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id=?;

SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE user_id = ? AND category_id = ?
```

To do that in the Eloquent relationship, you need to subquery, like so:

```
return $query->with(['posts' => function ($q) use ($category_id) {
    $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
}]);
```

Please comment if you need further info and I'll edit my answer.